# Call moveRowAt method in didSelectRowAt?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Is there a way that you can call

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to toIndexPath: IndexPath) {

   let affectedEvent = arrayMoved[fromIndexPath.row]
        arrayMoved.remove(at: fromIndexPath.row)
        arrayMoved.insert(affectedEvent, at: toIndexPath.row) }
```

in

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`tableView(_:moveRowAt:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614867-tableview) is a [delegate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349706/little-confused-on-delegates-in-objective-c), meaning it is a method that you should implement and let the system call you, not the other way around — normally you should not call a delegate method yourself.

If you want to tell the system to move a row, simply [call `moveRow(at:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614987-moverow) of the table view, e.g.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt ip: IndexPath) {
    tableView.moveRow(at: ip, to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: ip.section))
}
```

---

After communicating with OP, want OP actually wants to reorder the model to push the selected item to the end. The typical way to do this is something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt ip: IndexPath) {
    // update the model.
    model[ip.row].value = maxOfValue + 1
    sortModelAgain()

    // reload the model (note: no animation if using this)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

or, if you'd like to manually keep the view and model in sync:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt ip: IndexPath) {
    // update the model.
    model[ip.row].value = maxOfValue + 1
    sortModelAgain()

    // change the view to keep in sync of data.
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    let endRow = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: ip.section) - 1
    tableView.moveRow(at: ip, to: IndexPath(row: endRow, section: ip.section))
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: @Coder221 What do you want to fill `fromIndexPath` and `toIndexPath` in the `didSelectRowAt:`?

Comment: I like to fill toIndexPath

Comment: @Coder221 So what should `fromIndexPath` be?

Comment: fromIndexPath is when you select the row, then you remove it when it is moved programmatically and replace it with toIndexPath

Comment: OK so what should `toIndexPath` be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139610/discussion-between-coder221-and-kennytm).